# Extract and transform Data from Dataset

Tags: python, data-analysis

I have a Dataset that is in following format:

```
Time-Stamp (dd-mm-yyyy)   Temperature
```

I need to extract Day and Month from the Time-Stamp information from each observation in the series

Current Dataset format:

```
0   1981-01-01                                               20.7           
1   1981-01-02                                               17.9           
2   1981-01-03                                               18.8
```

Desired Dataset format:

```
month day temperature 
 1     1      20.7 
 1     2      17.9 
 1     3      18.8
 1     4      14.6
```

Comment: What is your datastructure (list, numpy array, pandas dataframe)?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is the code of your attempts?

Answer (score 0):

import the data into pandas dataframe, you'll have 3 columns, then the date column split it as:

```
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
df['day'] = df['date'].dt.day
```

where df is your dataframe and you will have your split data